# Solving 2 equations in 3 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find x , y in terms of z if :
$$x^3 + y^3 = z^3 , x^2 + y^2 = 1.1z^2$$
I tried : $$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2) = z^3 , (x+y)^2 -2xy = 1.1z^2$$
$$(x+y) (1.1z^2 -xy)$$
But i did not go on any more !

Comment: $x$ is easily eliminated ($a=1.1$)
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^6=(z^3-y^3)^2 =(a z^2-y^2)^3.
\end{eqnarray*}
This reduces to
\begin{eqnarray*}
2y^6-3ay^4z^2-2y^3z^3+3a^2y^2z^4+(1-a^3)z^6=0
\end{eqnarray*}
& I really don't fancy trying to solve that.

Comment: For $z=0$ there is only the solution $x=y=0$. Otherwise we have to solve the polynomial equation in $y$ and $z$. Could you specify, for this, whether $x,y,z$ are integers, or rational, or real, or complex numbers?

Comment: x , y and z are real numbers @Dietrch Burde

Answer (score 1):

For real numbers, we have, besides $x=y=z=0$ at most six real solutions for $y$, for a fixed $z$, because $y$ is a root of a polynomial of degree $6$.
Similarly, $x^6=(z^3-y^3)^2$. The polynomial equations imply, for example, for $z=1$, that $y$ is a root of the polynomial
$$
f(y)=2000y^6 - 3300y^4 - 2000y^3 + 3630y^2 - 331.
$$
The equation $f(y)=0$ has $4$ real solutions, and $x$ is given by
$$
x=\frac{y( - 2200y^4 - 2000y^3 + 1210y^2 + 3300y - 331)}{331}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $$(x/z)^3+(y/z)^3=1$$

And $$(x/z)^2+(y/z)^2 =1.1$$

Solve for $x/z$ and $y/z$ to get a parametric solution for $x,y,z$